# Tengo un error con Vue Router en el guardia beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs, vue-router

Hola estoy utilizando vue CLI con vue router.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo ese error.

1. Lo que hace es cachar si está logueado el usuario
2. Cachar si la ruta a la que se dirige es /login
3. Hacer la redirección según sea el caso.

El código:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (store.state.user.email == '') {
    if (from.path != '/login') {
      next({
        path: '/login'
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (from.path == '/login') {
      next({
        path: '/'
      });
    }
  }
  next();
})
```

Ya lo solucioné, la lógica está bien, solo que estaba utilizando from en lugar de to.

Comment: Saludos Alberto Ortega, en la parte inferior de esta página hay una caja de texto que tiene de título "Tu Respuesta", por favor, coloca lo que hayas realizado para solucionar tu pregunta, en 24 horas regresas para marcarla como aceptada, de tal manera que colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estaba utilizando el el origen en lugar del destino.

La solucion es muy simple

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (store.state.user.email == '') {
    if (to.path != '/login') {
      next({
        path: '/login'
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (to.path == '/login') {
      next({
        path: '/'
      });
    }
  }
  next();
})
```

La comparación que se debe de hacer siempre o en la mayoría de las veces es hacia el destino.

Por otra parte los argumentos de la función **beforeEach()** son los siguientes.

> **to** Hacia donde se  dirige las rutas.
>
> **from**  Origen donde de las rutas.
>
> **next** Callback define el estado de la ruta.